# Is it possible to use multiple value converters?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter, imultivalueconverter

So, .NET has a built in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` and that is nice for when I have a single boolean to convert to visibility. But when I have multiple conditions to control the visibility, I created my own `AndConverter` and `OrConverter` classes. They implement IMultiValueConverter so they can take in multiple boolean values to perform an `and` or `or` operation on them to output a single boolean.

The problem is that I need some way to "pipe" the output from my `AndConverter` or `OrConverter` into the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` but I don't see how that's possible. Do I have to create new converters that take multiple booleans and output a `Visibility`? I hope that is not the case because I also need to convert the result to a `string`, and possibly other things as well in the future. It would be nice to be able to just pipe the output from one converter into another converter instead of having to create new converters to handle every possible situation.

Comment: You need to convert to string?  Since BooleanToVisibilityConverter does not take a string input that does not help much.   Why would you need to convert a bool to string? - it has a ToString() method.

Comment: WPF does not just automatically call .ToString() on it.

Comment: Really?  So you have tried binding a TextBox to a boolean?

Comment: Yes, I have. Well, not a TextBox, but a TextBlock. Binding to a boolean property works but when you use an IMultiValueConverter to convert multiple booleans into 1 boolean it does not work.

Comment: Then write a method to do the bool. And have two converters that call it.

Comment: That's not what I asked for in this question. I already know that I can create multiple converters. I said I wanted to avoid having to create multiple converters if possible.

Comment: Multiple converters?  How many outputs besides string and visibility do you need?   You are not going to convert Boolean to Date or Decimal.  You are going to need a named converter in XAML.  What is big deal if the converters call a common method.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like what you're looking for with a regular `IValueConverter`:

```
public class BooleanConverter<T> : DependencyObject, IValueConverter {

    public static DependencyProperty FalseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "False", typeof( T ), typeof( BooleanConverter<T> ), new PropertyMetadata( default( T ) ) );

    public static DependencyProperty TrueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "True", typeof( T ), typeof( BooleanConverter<T> ), new PropertyMetadata( default( T ) ) );

    public T False {
        get { return (T) GetValue( FalseProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( FalseProperty, value ); }
    }

    public T True {
        get { return (T) GetValue( TrueProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( TrueProperty, value ); }
    }

    public BooleanConverter( T trueValue, T falseValue ) {
        True  = trueValue;
        False = falseValue;
    }

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
        bool b = false;
             if ( value is bool ) b = (bool) value;
        else if ( value is string ) b = bool.Parse( value as string );
        return b ? True : False;
}

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
        return value is T && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals( (T) value, True );
    }
}
```

Then I implemented many new classes that descend from the generic type.  For example:

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( bool ), typeof( Brush ) )]
public class BooleanToBrushConverter : BooleanConverter<Brush> {

    public BooleanToBrushConverter() :
        base( new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Black ), new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Red ) ) { }
}
```

You can probably do something similar for the `IMultiValueConverter` classes.  The `True` & `False` properties would still be there, it's just that the logic for deciding which property's value to return involves logically ANDing or ORing the values in the array passed.

Something like this:

```
public class AndConverter<T> : DependencyObject,  : DependencyObject, IMultiValueConverter{

    public static DependencyProperty FalseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "False", typeof( T ), typeof( AndConverter<T> ), new PropertyMetadata( default( T ) ) );

    public static DependencyProperty TrueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "True", typeof( T ), typeof( AndConverter<T> ), new PropertyMetadata( default( T ) ) );

    public T False {
        get { return (T) GetValue( FalseProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( FalseProperty, value ); }
    }

    public T True {
        get { return (T) GetValue( TrueProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( TrueProperty, value ); }
    }

    public AndConverter( T trueValue, T falseValue ) {
        True  = trueValue;
        False = falseValue;
    }

    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        return (<Your logic to compute the result goes here>) ? True : False;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        // . . .
    }
}
```

Then you can create your class for converting to Visibility:

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( bool ), typeof( Visibility ) )]
public class AndVisibilityConverter : AndConverter<Visibility> {

    public AndVisibilityConverter() :
        base( Visibility.Visible, Visibility.Hidden ) { }
}
```